# Unable to access Docker application from browser

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

I have a .NET Core 2.1 API which, when run via Visual Studio in Windows, receives a HTTP GET from the browser and successfully returns data from a MySQL DB.

I've been trying to add the API to a Docker container (inside Ubuntu) - this builds, but I can't access the API from the browser:

[image: Firefox]

**What I've tried**:

- Checking available ports. Here's the relevant output:

[image]

- Connecting using a different browser: In Chromium, it says 'This site can't be reached: **localhost** unexpectedly closed the connection.'
- Testing unused ports in the browser to see if this returns a different message - for Firefox, unused ports return 'Unable to connect' instead of 'Secure connection Failed', and in Chromium they return 'localhost refused to connect.' instead of 'localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.'
- In Firefox, configuring 'security.tls.insecure_fallback_hosts' to 'localhost'.
- Double-checking that ports are mapped correctly in docker-compose.yml - under 'ports' for the relevant container, 44329 is mapped to 44329.
- Running a DB query when the API starts and logging the result: this is successful. I run `docker-compose up`, the API starts, connects to the DB container, and it logs the result of an SQL query to a text file. So the problem is unlikely to be anything to do with the database.
- Logging GET requests: Inside Windows, the GET requests are successfully logged, but in the Ubuntu Docker container, they're not.

This might be relevant: In Windows, the API only works properly if you start it from Visual Studio. If you execute `dotnet webapi.dll`, you get this output

```
...\netcoreapp2.1>dotnet webapi.dll
...
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

So here it's not running on 44329; instead it's accessible via 5001 in the browser, where you get this message which is not chill at all: 
[image]
Clicking 'ADVANCED' allows you to continue to the API.

- So I've also tried connecting via 5001 in Ubuntu without luck.

Here's the output from 'docker-compose up':

```
matt@Matt-Ubuntu:~/docker2$ docker-compose up
Starting docker2_mysql_1 ... done
Starting docker2_dbmodelmapper_1 ... done
Attaching to docker2_mysql_1, docker2_dbmodelmapper_1
... (mysql stuff) ...
dbmodelmapper_1  | Hosting environment: Production
dbmodelmapper_1  | Content root path: /app
dbmodelmapper_1  | Now listening on: http://[::]:80
dbmodelmapper_1  | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

- Seeing the port 80, I've tried connecting to that, without success.
- The relevant container as shown by `docker ps` is:

  [image]

What kind of issue am I looking at here?

Comment: what's the output of `docker ps`

Comment: Have added that to the end of the question

Comment: Could it be a firewall issue?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be - ufw is disabled and iptables is configured by Docker to allow those ports.

Comment: When you tried connecting to port 80, did you have the port published? The output above doesn't show port 80.

Comment: I don't know why it says listening on port 80, but I did just try adding 80 to the listed ports - no luck.  Something is happening on 44329, as shown by the different error message when connecting to it.

Comment: @matt_rule yes it is listening on port 80 inside the container but the `docker ps` doesn't show a mapping from container port 80 to your host, it only shows 5000-5001 mapping and 44329 mapping to the host but that's not used but the `dotnet` process.

Comment: the certificate errors suggests you didn't trust your asp.net core development https certificate. use `dotnet dev-certs https` to manage/export your certificate and configure local trust.

Comment: @matt_rule Martin Ullrich is right. Docker executes your API in Production mode which causes it to be listening on port 80. Your docker port mapping does not map any of your host ports to the container port 80 though... have you tried anything like `-p 80:80`? You might need to expose that port in your `Dockerfile` as well

Comment: Thanks all, have added the answer.  Incorrectly exposing port 80 was the issue as you pointed out.

Comment: Self-correction: incorrectly *listening on*, not exposing.  Exposing 80 would have fixed the issue as you said!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by multiple people in the comments (thanks sp0gg, Martin Ullrich and Daniel Lerps), the API was incorrectly listening on port 80.

The solution was to map port 5000 to 44329 in docker-compose.yml for the API container, and also modify the Dockerfile to pass ports in as arguments to dotnet when starting the ASP.NET API:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "webapi.dll", "--urls", "http://*:5000;http://*:5001"]
```